# cmake and clang++ windows build instead of MSVC

Tags: cmake, clang, clang++

I am trying to create a build environment using cmake and i have both MSVC and clang installed on my system.

When I run cmake with the default settings it detectts MSVC as my cxx compiler.

However, I would like to use clang++ instead.

I tried specifying clang like this: `cmake  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++`

but even after that it still uses MSVC..

How can I tell it to use clang instead?

Comment: Did you remove CMakeCache.txt before switching the compiler?

Comment: You're probably still using the default generator which seems to be visual studio in this case. Have you checked for some weirdness in the generated project. As mentioned by ixSci you won't be able to change the compiler after the initial configuration; you need to set up the project from scratch in a new directory or just clear the old build dir before running the cmake configuration step again.

Comment: yes. I removed the CMakeCache.txt. I also remove all files that cmake generated. I only kept my source and CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I even created new project from scratch in a new directory... and it is still using MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the complete path of the `clang` compiler. E.g.,

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/clang
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to ensure that CLANG is visible through a regular command prompt window. If not then you need to put the CLANG installed directory path to your PATH environment variable.

In my case I had clang-cl installed through Visual Studio but it was still not visible through a regular command prompt window.

Regular command prompt window output:

```
>clang-cl -v
'clang++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Developer command prompt window output:

```
>clang-cl -v
clang version 12.0.0
Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin
```

Moreover, I simply use the following command: `cmake -T ClangCL` to generate the project on a Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio 2019 Professional Edition.

This is the output I get:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.0 with MSVC-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 12.0.0 with MSVC-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
```

I have tested the same on another Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition and it works fine too.