# Generate VS2022 project files with CMake which use clang

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I am trying to generate `Visual Studio 2022` project files using `CMake` and the `clang` compiler.

Currently, if I call:

```
cmake -S . -B build -G "Ninja Multi-Config" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

I can compile and build my project fine using `Ninja`.

Now, I have tried to get this to work using `VS2022`, however if I simply just call:

```
cmake -S . -B build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

it compiles the project using `msvc`, which is not intended.

Now, if i change this to include the toolchain:

```
cmake -S . -B build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T="ClangCL" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

It says that it can't find the compilers specified. If I swap these with the path to the specified compilers, it will seemingly run, but it will generate an error in the `CMakeErrors.txt`, which says:

`clang: error: no input files`.

So, my question is, can anyone help me to build `VS2022` project files that compile with `clang` using `CMake`?

my `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Test)

# Use C23 standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Use C++23 standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Compiler setting
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")

# Include subprojects
add_subdirectory(TestLib)
add_subdirectory(Runtime)
```

Comment: have you installed the [clang toolset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170#install-1)?

Comment: Yes, clang / llvm are installed. If i build my project using `Ninja` like i mentioned in my post, everything compiles properly with clang.

Comment: no, have you installed the clang toolset, read the link I posted

Comment: I have also installed the toolset you mentioned in the link. I reference it with -T="CIClang", like how it is displayed in the project files. I can start a project in visual studio and presumably compile it with clang. However, i want to build these project files using cmake

Comment: other related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-cmake. potential dup target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71705430/11107541

Comment: when you ran CMake configuration, did you run it from a Visual Studio Developer Prompt? You might need to in order to be able to specify non-full paths and get lookup from the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @starball I just tried, but that gives me the same error. I was just using a `.bat` file.

Comment: @starball also, I read the docs you send, but that is for a `CMake project`. I am trying to generate `VS2022 project` files using `CMake`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can include a `FILEPATH=""` to the command.

So, changing to the following command:

```
cmake -S . -B build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T="ClangCL" -D_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX="ClangCL" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe"
```

<strike>build my project succesfully</strike>

**EDIT:**

after I deleted my build files and rebuild using the above command, i get a new error:

```
  Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1575, 5): [MSB6006] "llvm-lib.exe" exited with code 1.
```

When i search for this, i read something about this being a common issue in an earlier build of `VS2022` when building static libraries. Currently, I am on `17.6.4`.

However, when I use `set LTCG="No"`, the same error occurs.

Comment: that's a [type specification](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry).